# How to find the value of an unknown exponent?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

E.g. I have the question:

$$2^{4x+1} = 128$$

I solved this by knowing that $128 = 2^7$ and therefore $x$ must equal $1.5$.

However, is there a way of solving this without knowing that $128 = 2^7$?

Comment: Did you mean $2^{4x+1}=128$?

Comment: $$128 = 2^{7}$$

Comment: Yes, I did mean that.

Comment: $x=2$ doesn't work.   There is no need to "know" that $128=2^7$...if you wanted to solve $2^y=z$ you could just take $\log_2$ of both sides to get $y=\log_2 z$.

Comment: Well, now that you've added "without knowing that $128 = 2^7$"... What exactly do you mean by that??? If you take $\log_2$ on $128$, and you get $7$, then does that mean that you "know that $128 = 2^7$?

Comment: So the answer is take log2 of both sides.

Comment: he means how does he reverse the process of '2 is raised to the power of...'  Which can be accomplished by taking log, then using algebra, then anti-log

Comment: Well, part of the answer, yes... But how would you "know" the value of $\log_2128$? And if you do know it, then doesn't that mean that you know $2^7=128$???

Comment: Just put it in a calculator?

Comment: The point is that there should be a way of answering the question without knowing *already* that 128 = 2^7.

Comment: There is a way of doing that, just use logs as has been suggested. You don't NEED to know that $2^7 = 128$. It is a systematic method of solving a general exponential equaation

Comment: If you didn't already know that $128=2^7$, you would begin by finding the prime factorization of $128$.

Comment: Is it ok if I know all of my $2^n$ all the way up to $4096$ due to that one game called "$\it2048$"?

Comment: @top_systems_programmer: Step 1: notice that $2^{7}=128.$ Step 2: Do as you did before. I don't see why knowledge of a general fact is reason to reject a valid method of solution, at least in this case. Sometimes you just have to know something (or at least, it *really really* helps) in order to figure out something else. This is the purpose of [lemmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(mathematics)), and coming up with the key lemmata is frequently *the* way to make progress on difficult problems.

Comment: Well. maybe the point is, if you don't know log2(128) is 7 how you will calculate it. So actually we must add this information to complete it. Not just say log and done https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation

Answer (score 38, accepted):

... and without logarithms or knowing any powers of $2$ other than the most trivial one ...  \begin{align*}
2^{4x+1} &= 128  \\
2^{4x+1-1} = 2^{4x} &= 128/2 = 64  \\
2^{4x-1} &= 32  \\
2^{4x-2} &= 16  \\
2^{4x-3} &= 8  \\
2^{4x-4} &= 4  \\
2^{4x-5} &= 2  \\
2^{4x-6} &= 1 = 2^0 \text{,}  \\
\end{align*}
so  $4x-6 = 0$ and $x = 6/4 = 3/2$.

Comment: This is actually the real solution. Any solution involving log mean you must know that 128 is 2^7 so this should be marked as answer

Comment: @Thaina: See my comments (and the comment-thread in general) on the question itself. In addition, for this method to work, $128$ has to be a perfect power of $2$, and whoever deploys this method needs to know it. So in terms of "knowing", there is not much difference between using $\log_2$ and using this method.

Comment: I think he should've stopped at $2^{4x-5}$, as establishing $2^0=1$ may not be as obvious as $2^1=2$.

Comment: @Thaina Eh, no, replace 128 in the question by any arbitrary number, say 185, and the log based solutions still work.

Comment: @Thaina - the solutions using log don't require knowing that 128 is 2^7, in fact it's the opposite, it provides a general solution

Comment: How would this answer work if the right side of the equation is 127 instead of 128 ?

Comment: @Eric Towers The code didn't render.

Comment: @freethinker36 : I bet you are using the latest release of Chrome.  There are a number of comments in the past few days about MathJax rendering problems in the most recent Chrome.  [Not](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/774/google-chrome-not-rendering-latex-in-browser) that [Chrome](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/sometimes-mathjax-does-not-render-some-valid-symbols-an-example) having [rendering](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30842/mathjax-formulas-hidden-behind-text) problems is rare.

Comment: @EricTowers Using firefox

Comment: @freethinker36 : As am I.  Renders fine for me. Do you have a script blocker running and/or does any other display math on this site render for you?

Comment: I am using the latest firefox which has more features for privacy. Some websites are not liking it and don't let me use them telling them i have ad blocker. I dont have ad blocker, unless there is a built in one in firefox.

Comment: @freethinker36 : So there's nothing I can do to fix Firefox of the MathJax rendering from MSE.  I use Firefox with NoScript and I have to allow ajax.googleapis.com, cloudflare.com, and sstatic.net to get MSE to update its notifications bar, update pages dynamically, and to render MathJax.  I'd be happier if MSE hosted the code it used, but that would be expecting other people to responsibly pin versions of libraries they critically rely upon, so I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: Aha! It renders with the Edge browser of Microsoft.

Answer (score 23):

$2^{4x+1}=128\iff$

$\log_22^{4x+1}=\log_2128\iff$

${4x+1}=7\iff$

${4x}=6\iff$

${x}=6/4$

Comment: This is just giving a different name to "knowing that $128=2^7$".

Comment: @Jack M: Not if the step from second to third line has been done by actually computing the $\log_2$ of 128; of course after that you probably *know* it.

Comment: @JackM: See my comments (and the comment-thread in general) on the question itself.

Comment: @JackM To put it another way - simply "knowing" that 128=2^7 is a piece of declarative information.  Computing the logarithm of 128 is applying a functional algorithm to come to the same answer.  If you know how to compute a logarithm you can "forget" that you ever knew any specific solutions.

Answer (score 18):

$2^{4x+1}=128$

$\log 2^{4x+1}=\log 128$

$(4x + 1) \times \log 2 = \log 128$      - from properties of logs

$x = \frac{1}{4}(\frac {\log 128}{log (2)} - 1)   = 3/2$

note that you can use any logarithm, log base 10 or 'ln' - or any other 'base' of logarithms you might have (with log10 and loge being the commonly found  ones on calculators, spreadsheets etc )  you have to use your chosen type of log consistently of course

Comment: I think this answer is best beacuse it's the only one to point out that you do not need to use log-base-2.  Given the OPs wording, this strikes me as a key insight towards what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 11):

To solve your equation, take the base-2 logarithm of both sides:

$$ \log_2 2^{4x+1} = \log_2 128 $$
$$ 4x+1 = 7 $$
$$ x = 1.5$$

> However, is there a way of solving this without knowing that $128=2^7$?

Well, this piece of information is equivalent to “knowing that $\log_2 128 = 7$”, so no.

Comment: calculators don't often have log base 2, you can just use any type of log, log 10 or ln(base e) both work.  lol, when he says 'know' he means 'be able to spot', not work it out with a calculator

Comment: @Cato, but there's always the base change formula, y'know.

Answer (score 7):

It's very easy. Let's assume we have

$$k_1 ^ {k_2 * x + k_3} = k_4   $$

Where all the $k$'s are knowns, and the x is unknown.

We begin by removing the $k_3$ from the result ($k_4$) by dividing it by $k_1 ^ {k_3}$. The result thus obtained should be equal to:

$$k_1 ^ {k_2 * x}$$

As you can see we no longer have to deal with the $k_3$.
Next we raise the result above to the power of $\frac{1}{k_2}$.
That is, we find out what number we have to raise to the power of $k_2$ to reach at the result $k_1 ^ {k_2 * x}$. The answer should be equal to:

$$k_1 ^ x$$

Now finally from this result we can find out the value of $x$ by using a mathematical operation that lets us know, what number you have to raise a known other number to, to reach at a known result.

This operation is the logaritm. It's method of use is as follows:
Let's assume $a ^ b = c$. The logarithm can be used to find out $b$, and it is then written as $\log_a c$.

So, to find out x in the result above, we use $\log_{k_1} result$ where $result$ is the value of the result obtained from previous operations.

Comment: This is actually (the start of) the best answer, because it provides a step-by-step method for driving at the result of *any* problem of the sort posed by the asker.

Answer (score 3):

$$2^{4x+1}=128\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}4x+1=7\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}4x=6\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}x=\frac64=\frac32$$

This is done as one would usually have:

$$2^y=128\iff y=\log_2(128)=7$$

Comment: That's not what OP meant; see the comment-thread on the question.

Comment: @barakmanos fixed.

Comment: Well, the OP has just added "without knowing that $128 = 2^7$" (whatever that means)...

Comment: @barakmanos ah the frustration...

Comment: knowing that $128^7$ would mean to me that it is a fact that can be spotted by inspection, as opposed to $3^4.416508=128$ which isn't likely to be figured out without a calculation.

Comment: @Cato one would most likely go straight to the calculator or leaving it in that form.

Comment: ah come on $2^x = 128$ can be solved with no calculator if you work in computing

Comment: @Cato That's like saying "you can bake without a hearth if you have an oven".

Comment: @G. Bach - what I mean is if you worked with the old style stuff like bits, bytes and kilobytes - you'd probably notice that 128 is a power of 2 - I wouldn't personally 'notice' that 2401 is a power of 7 for example, I know some people would though.

Answer (score 1):

### This answer is based on that of user504882, and may be considered a heavily-edited (and extended) version thereof.

Let's assume we have

$$k_1 ^ {k_2 * x + k_3} = k_4,   $$

where all the $k$s are known and the $x$ is unknown. As with almost all problems in elementary algebra, the goal is to isolate (i.e., *solve for*) $x$, and each step we take will be with that in mind.

We begin by removing the $k_3$ from the left-hand side of the equation by dividing it by $k_1 ^ {k_3}$. The equation thus obtained is:

$$k_1 ^ {k_2 * x} = \frac{k_4}{k_1 ^ {k_3}}.$$

As you can see, we no longer have to deal with the $k_3$ in the left-hand side.
Next we further isolate $x$ on the left-hand side by raising both sides of the equation to the power of $\frac{1}{k_2}$. The resulting equation is:

$$k_1 ^ x = {(\frac{k_4}{k_1 ^ {k_3}})}^{\frac{1}{k_2}}.$$

Now finally we can isolate $x$ by using a mathematical operation that lets us invert exponentiation; i.e., it lets us know what number we have to raise a given number to the power of in order to reach at a known result.

This operation is the *logarithm*. Its definition is as follows:
Let's assume $a ^ b = c$. The logarithm can be used to find out $b$, and it is then written as 
$$b = \log_a(c).$$

(Note that $a$ is called the *base* of $\log_a$, since it's the base of the exponential expression $a^b$.)

So, to isolate $x$ in the equation above, we use $\log_{k_1}$ to produce the equation
$$x = \log_{k_1}({(\frac{k_4}{k_1 ^ {k_3}})}^{\frac{1}{k_2}}).$$

Note that logarithm rules can simplify this formula to

$$x = \frac{\log_{k_1}(k_4) - k_3}{k_2}.$$

As others have pointed out, however, when applied to the original problem, all of this fancy shuffling reduces to knowing that $128 = 2^7$ or, in the parlance of logarithms, $7 = \log_2(128).$ But what if we didn't have this special knowledge? What if the original equation were something like $54^{17x + 99} = 42$? How the heck could we reasonably solve *that* equation?

We do this by manipulating logarithms. It turns out that we've found two types of logarithms really useful, to the point that most standard calculators come equipped with them: the logarithms based in the number 10 and the well-known constant $e$. These both make sense, because our everyday number system uses 10s, and $e$ has some special properties that aren't relevant to this particular discussion. Regardless, $\log_e$ is used so often it's often called the *natural* logarithm, and the base is usually omitted (so that when you see $\log(c)$ it's understood to mean $\log_e(c)$).

So now, since we can easily work with logarithms in either of these bases (even if we have no idea what $e$ actually is or what it's otherwise used for), we just have to wonder whether or not there's a way for turning a logarithm based in an arbitrary number, say $a$, to a logarithm based in $e$ (or 10). And there is! Here's a formula for *changing bases* on a logarithm, from base $a$ to base $t$ (for arbitrary values of $a$ and $t$):

$$\log_{t}(c) = \frac{\log_a(c)}{\log_a(t)}.$$

(This formula isn't too difficult to prove, but it relies on some properties of logarithms that are also beyond the scope of this discussion, so we make take it as given.)

Augmenting our cooked-up formula with the change of base formula gets us

$$ x = \frac{\log_{k_1}(k_4) - k_3}{k_2} = \frac{\frac{\log(k_4)}{\log(k_1)} - k_3}{k_2}.$$

Now, that looks like a bit of intimidating alphabet soup, but it's not too difficult to replace all the $k$s with their respective numbers from the original problem. This yields $k_1 = 2$, $k_2 = 4$, $k_3 = 1$, and $k_4 = 128.$ Thus

$$ x = \frac{\frac{\log(128)}{\log(2)} - 1}{4} = \frac{7 - 1}{4} = \frac{6}{4} = 1.5.$$

It is left as an exercise for the reader to solve $54^{17x + 99} = 42$ for $x$, using this or any other method.

A question one can play around with: Is it possible to generalise our formula to quadratic polynomials? To general polynomials in the reals? To general complex polynomials? If you know, you may want to answer my question [Name and Generalise This Linear Exponent Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060399/name-and-generalise-this-linear-exponent-formula).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the bisection method, because the next problem may not have nice integer solutions.  For example, what if the right side of the equation is 138 instead of 128?

So start f(x) = 2^(4*x+1).  Let L = 0 and U = 10.  Verify that f(L) < 128 and also f(U) > 128.

Calculate m = (L+U)/2 and f(m).  If f(m) < 128, let L=m and repeat. If f(m)>128, let U=m and repeat.   If f(m)=0, let x=m and quit.

This process may never get you an exact solution, but L and U will approach each other and sandwich the solution close enough for all practical purposes.

I confess, this was inspired by my recent discovery of how Euler computed logarithms to 40 or more places.