# Name and Generalise This Linear Exponent Formula

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, recreational-mathematics

In [How to find the value of an unknown exponent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2058765/how-to-find-the-value-of-an-unknown-exponent/2060311), [user504882](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305385/user504882) provided an answer which inspired me to develop the following formula for solving exponential problems of the  form $a^{k_1x + k_0} = b$ for $x$:

$$ x = \log_a[(\frac{b}{a^{k_0}})^{\frac{1}{k_1}}]. $$

On inspection, I see this can be simplified to

$$ x = \frac{\log_a(b) - k_0}{k_1} ,$$

following well-known laws of logarithms. Does this formula have a name? Can it be generalised, say to exponents with rational quadratics or complex polynomials?

(If this sort of question is more approprate for the Math Exchange, feel free to migrate it.)

Comment: If you simply take the $\log_a$ of both sides of the original equation, you get $k_1x+k_0=\log_a b$ directly.

Comment: *smacks forehead* Of course. I should have seen that from the beginning of the linked question.